# Combinatorics 2 variables

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

A very simple question to answere for anyone with basic knowledge of statistics I would presume:

For a (large) fleet of two different vehicle types A and B, with equal fleet share (50%), what are the chances of type A being involved in an accident between 2 vehicles.

I.e if I pick 100 random accidents involving 2 vehicles how many would statistically be between A and B, A and A, and B and B?

Comment: There's not enough information. It depends on the chance of each vehicle being involved in a collision. Imagine if you had a fleet of $50$ Humvees and $50$ RC cars. Clearly they're not equally likely to hit each other.

Comment: Sorry, the chances are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $P(A $involved$) = 0.5 , P(B$ involved$) = 0.5$ Using the AND rule, we find the probability of A and B occuring by multiplying the probabillties. Therefore, the probability of:

$$P(A \text{and} B) = 0.5 *0.5=0.25$$
$$P(B \text{and} B) = 0.5 *0.5=0.25$$
$$P(B \text{and} A) = 0.5 *0.5=0.25$$
$$P(A \text{and} A) = 0.5 *0.5=0.25$$

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!